# Not getting information level logs in my webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights, nlog

I am using app insights for logging.

So i noticed that in traces i am only getting logs that are related to warning,error and critical but i need the info as well.

Below is my code

in program.cs

```
logging.AddFilter<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>(typeof(Program).FullName, LogLevel.Trace);
```

in appsettings.json i have the below rules

```
"NLog": {
    "autoReload": true,
    "throwConfigExceptions": true,
    "internalLogLevel": "warn",
    "internalLogFile": "${currentdir}/Logs/internal-nlog.txt",
    "extensions": [
      {
        "assembly": "NLog.Extensions.Logging"
      },
      {
        "assembly": "NLog.Web.AspNetCore"
      },
      {
        "assembly": "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget"
      }
    ],
    "default-wrapper": {
      "type": "AsyncWrapper",
      "overflowAction": "Block"
    },
    "targets": {
      "blackHole": {
        "type": "Null",
        "formatMessage": false
      },
      "aiTarget": {
        "type": "ApplicationInsightsTarget"
      },
      "asyncWrapperConsoleTarget": {
        "type": "AsyncWrapper",
        "timeToSleepBetweenBatches": 0,
        "queueLimit": 1000000,
        "batchSize": 1000,
        "target": {
          "name": "ConsoleTarget",
          "type": "ColoredConsole",
          "layout": "CorrelationId= ${aspnet-item:variable=CorrelationId} ${aspnet-user-identity} ${date:universalTime=true}|${level:uppercase=true}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}|${logger}|${all-event-properties}",
          "rowHighlightingRules": [
            {
              "condition": "level == LogLevel.Debug",
              "foregroundColor": "DarkGray"
            },
            {
              "condition": "level == LogLevel.Info",
              "foregroundColor": "Gray"
            },
            {
              "condition": "level == LogLevel.Warn",
              "foregroundColor": "Yellow"
            },
            {
              "condition": "level == LogLevel.Error",
              "foregroundColor": "Red"
            },
            {
              "condition": "level == LogLevel.Fatal",
              "foregroundColor": "Red",
              "backgroundColor": "White"
            }
          ]

        }
      },
 "rules": {
      "0": {
        "logger": "Microsoft.*",
        "minLevel": "debug",
        "writeTo": "blackHole",
        "final": true
      },
      "1": {
        "logger": "System.Net.Http.HttpClient.*",
        "minLevel": "info",
        "writeTo": "blackHole",
        "final": true
      },
      "2": {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "debug",
        "writeTo": "asyncWrapperDatabase"
      },
      "3": {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "trace",
        "writeTo": "aiTarget"
      }
    }
```

i have written the below code in my cs file

```
_logger.LogInformation("Testing info log");
            _logger.LogDebug("Testing debug log");
            _logger.LogError("Testing error log");
            _logger.LogTrace("Testing trace log");
            _logger.LogCritical("Testing critical log");
            _logger.LogWarning("Testing warning log");
```

From the above i only get logs for error, critical and warning. What is wrong that i am doing and why am i not getting information level logs?

Comment: are you using some 3rd-party tools for logging? I didn't see such rules in appsettings.json , can you provide some reference docs?

Comment: @IvanYangi am using nlog

Comment: can you show us which packages are you using?

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Missing-trace%5Cdebug-logs-in-ASP.NET-Core-3%3F

Comment: @RolfKristensen still i am not getting info level logs even in the console window i see only the above 3 logs, i dont see information level logs

Comment: @ashish, did you right click the appsettings.json -> properties, then set "copy to output directory" as "copy if newer"?

Comment: @IvanYang it is already copy if newer

Comment: @ashish, ok, can you show us the completed appsettings.json?

Comment: @IvanYang i have edited the code and added complete appsettings.json file

Comment: Remember to check for any environment-specific appsettings.json. Ex. `appsettings.development.json` or `appsettings.production.json` (Also mentioned in the wiki-page)

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 problems here.

- Regarding app insights issue, you need to add app insights related config section in your `appsettings.json` (I see only NLog part in your shared config). Even though you are allowing at nlog level, but app insights adapter is filtering here. Default is Warning or above. As per [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#create-filter-rules-in-configuration-with-appsettingsjson), something like below would fix your problem.

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

NOTE: ApplicationInsights/LogLevel should be nested inside the Logging as above if you notice carefuly.

- Regarding the console logging issue, your rule has wrong target name. `asyncWrapperDatabase` should be `asyncWrapperConsoleTarget`.